# Adding Bracket for a giver number in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i need to add a N number of brackets for the selected ListItem from list boxes for `a given number from a variable`. say ex. if `i pass 5 from` a variable it has to add the 5 `brackets` at the end of my list item values. can someone give me an idea

thanks

Comment: some sample data and sample code would be useful to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bracket, isn't it? `(`

I don't know where exactly you have a problem with, but you can create a string with repeating characters with the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) overload:

```
int bracketCount = 5;
string brackets = new string('(', bracketCount);
```

So if you want to add these brackets to the selected item in the `ListBox`:

```
listBox1.SelectedItem.Text += brackets;
```